# "The package could not be installed" when updating plugins, themes, and core files on WampServer

Tags: updates, upgrade, localhost, local-installation

Whenever I update anything on my local WordPress development site, whether it be plugins, themes, or the WP 3.7.1 update, I get this error message:

> Unpacking the update…
>
> The package could not be installed.: PCLZIP_ERR_BAD_FORMAT (-10) :
>   Unable to find End of Central Dir Record signature
>
> Installation Failed

I'm using WampServer 2.4, with Apache 2.0.63, PHP 5.2.11, and MySQL 5.0.88.

Comment: Are you running low on space on the partition/drive where you're trying to do the unzip?  [Details](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/pclzip_err_bad_format-1)

Comment: Also... Have you tried updating Apache & PHP version in Wamp? I'm not receiving any errors with WP 3.7.1 on Wamp with Apache 2.2.6 & PHP 5.3...

Comment: @PatJ No, I have plenty of space on my drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had same issue today on my new server.
After a while i realize that zip/unzip is not active in my apache/php . When i recompile my apache with zip extension , problem solved.